# PHP 'USE' operator in classes and extended classes

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to understand how to use `USE` in base and extended classes. I have searched around but I don't think I have the correct terminology.

Let's say my base class looks like

```
namespace App\Classes;

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Title;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Chart;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Legend;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\PlotArea;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\DataSeries;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\DataSeriesValues;

class ExcelReport
{
    public $spreadsheet;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->spreadsheet = null;

    }
}
```

and then I extended that class

```
namespace App\Classes;


class MonthlyExcelReport extends ExcelReport
{
    public $id;

    public function __construct(int $id)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->id = $id;

    }

    public function build()
    {
       $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to get the call to `IOFactory` in the extended class to recognize that `use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;` is present in the base class?

I currently get this error `Class 'App\Classes\Gap\IOFactory' not found` and I don't want to have to repeat all of those `use` statements in the extended class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

Namespace is there to allow you to have two classes named the same, but in a different namespace.

Imagine the class `Animal\Bear\Claw` and `Machinery\Compactor\Claw`, are things possible with namespaces, when we needed ugly class names like `Animal_Bear_Claw` and `Machinery_Compactor_Claw` before the introduction of namespaces in PHP.

Now when you instanciate or use those classes, you don't want to allways have to go in the extends and say

```
new \Animal\Bear\Claw();
```

You want to be able to say: "*I am in the context of an Animal Factory Pattern and will basically act upon the classes under the Animal namespace, not the Machinery's ones*"

So you go:

```
use Animal\Bear\Claw;

new Claw();
```

Or

```
use Animal\Bear;

new Bear\Claw();
```

Or even, with aliases

```
use Animal\Bear as MyTeddyBear;

new MyTeddyBear\Claw();
```

And so, inheriting another class from another containing uses, just does nothing, you'll have to repeat your uses, maybe simplifying them, and most likely, not add uses for class you actually do not use in the said class (*did you know that good IDE does prompt you about unused use statement present in your classes and help you add the good ones to your `use` statements?*).

---

The use statement are not like an include like you seems to believe it.

It is just there to say: "*thanks to namespaces, I can have multiple classes with the same name, now the class I want to use is actually under the namespace defined by `use`*"

You are not forced to state a full namespace either in your `use` statements.

For example:

```
namespace App\Classes;

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;

class MonthlyExcelReport extends ExcelReport
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
       $workSheet = new Worksheet();
    }
}
```

Could be shortened this way:

```
namespace App\Classes;

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet; // This means "all the classes that I am going to use, if not in the same namespace as the current class (App\Classes) would come from the namespace PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet"

class MonthlyExcelReport extends ExcelReport
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       $reader = PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
       $workSheet = new PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet();
    }
}
```

Further reading:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php

Answer (score 1):

Use operator is used to "include" a class.
If you don't use "Use" operator, than you can include as "full path".

In your case:

```
$reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
```

Should be:

```
$reader = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
```

Comment: So the 'use' statements in the base class don't propagate into the extended classes?